# jquery not(active) doesn't work

Tags: jquery, animation, hover

The next chunk of code doesn't work and I can't find out why.
The animation is working well, but the `a:not(active)` part is not working.

```
<div id="SDS-menu-wrapper">
        <ul id="SDS-menu">
         <li id="SDS-m-1" class="SDS-menu-li"><a href="#">item a</a></li>
         <li id="SDS-m-2" class="SDS-menu-li"><a href="#">item b</a></li>
         <li id="SDS-m-3" class="SDS-menu-li"><a href="#">item c</a></li>
         <li id="SDS-m-4" class="SDS-menu-li"><a href="#">item d</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>



jQuery(document).ready(function() {


jQuery('[id^=SDS-m-]').click(function() {
    var m_index = this.id.replace('SDS-m-', '');
    jQuery( "#SDS-menu .SDS-menu-li a" ).removeClass( "active" );
    jQuery( "#SDS-m-"+m_index+" a" ).addClass( "active" );
});



jQuery('#SDS-menu li a:not(active)').hover(function() {
jQuery(this).stop().animate({ top: -4 }, 100, "easeOutBounce");
}, function() { jQ(this).stop().animate({ top: 0 }, 400, "easeOutBounce");
});

});
```

Comment: Since you're adding and removing the `active` class dynamically, you have to use event delegation to bind handlers to it. Otherwise, your `hover` binding will only be bound to elements that were active when the document was loaded.

Comment: However, `hover` is not a real event, so you can't delegate it, you have to bind `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution:

```
jQuery(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {   
                    jQuery(this).stop().animate({ top: -3 }, 100, "easeOutBounce");
                },
    mouseleave: function () {
                    jQuery(this).stop().animate({ top: 3 }, 400, "easeOutBounce");
                }
}, "#SDS-menu li a:not(.active)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Typo

```
jQuery('#SDS-menu li a:not(.active)').hover(function() {
                           ^ added . here for class selector
```

References

[**:not()**](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

[class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)